# No active UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRCameraSubsystem is available

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, ar-foundation

I want to make an AR foundation project but I keep getting this problem .Can someone helps me please ?

No active UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems.XRCameraSubsystem is available.Please ensure that a valid loader configuration exists in the XR project settings

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work you have to go into project settings XR Plug-in Management and select the XR plug-in providers you need for your project.
Once I ticked ARCore the camera started working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If like me, you already tried to check ARCore in XR Management and it's still a black screen, you might have to install on your phone the Google AR kit or something, that was my problem.

Comment: yes, sometimes this will be the problem